# What is the difference or relationship between JEP and JCP

Tags: java

What is the difference or relationship between JEP (JDK Enhancement-Proposal) and JCP (Java Community Process)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about organizational procedures rather than programming.

Comment: Wikipedia articles: [Java Community Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process) and [JDK Enhancement Proposal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Enhancement_Proposal). The latter article has this to say about the relationship between the two: "_The JEP process is not intended to replace the Java Community Process, which is still required to approve changes in the Java API or language but rather to allow for OpenJDK committers to work more informally before becoming a formal Java Specification Request._".

Answer (score 2):

According to [JEP 1](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/1), the primary goal of JDK Enhancement-Proposal (JEP) is:

> to produce a regularly-updated list of proposals to serve as the long-term Roadmap for **JDK Release Projects** and related efforts.

According to the [JCP glossary](https://jcp.org/en/introduction/glossary#J):

> [The] Java Community Process (JCP) [is] the formal process [...] for developing or revising Java technology Specifications.

To answer your question: JEPs are proposals for new features of the JDK and the JCP  produce new specifications (JSR) with a broader range such as [JPA 2.2 for persistence (JSR 338)](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr338/index.html) or [JAX-RS 2.1 for RESTful Web Services (JSR 370)](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr370/index.html).